# Determine only one contact SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

The main question is: How to determine only one contact?

part of code:

```
extension GameScene : SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodyA = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask
    let bodyB = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    let ball = BitmaskCategory.ball
    let bucket = BitmaskCategory.bucket



    if bodyA == ball && bodyB == bucket || bodyA == bucket && bodyB == ball {
        print("contact")
//            block.run(SKAction.repeatForever(blockInstanse.rotateBlock(block: block)))

    }
}}
```

When I put [ball in bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWg3N.png), i have that [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c73Yv.png) because ball has bouncing effect.
Want to write some logic in that func but I can't because have several contacts.
Tried to change ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask in "if" condition but without success too.
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ball or bucket can set a flag on the first contact, you can check inside the **didBegin** and run action if is true, like:

```
var isFirstContact = true

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodyA = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask
    let bodyB = contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    let ball = BitmaskCategory.ball
    let bucket = BitmaskCategory.bucket



    if bodyA == ball && bodyB == bucket || bodyA == bucket && bodyB == ball {
        if isFirstContact {
            isFirstContact = false
            // block.run(SKAction.repeatForever(blockInstanse.rotateBlock(block: block)))
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: It is working, thank you. I also added isFirstContact = true in my touchesBegan() because my ball spawned by tap.